# Method in Date extension not found in one class while works in another

Tags: swift, beta, xcode13

I've a small extension for the `Date` type with some simple helper methods like

```swift
extension Date
{
    func dateByAdding(components: DateComponents) -> Date?
    {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: self)
    }
```

Now there's one class where Xcode 13.0 beta 2 keeps telling me `Type 'Date' has no member 'dateByAdding'` while in another class the extension works as expected.

All files are 100% swift and all relevant files have a Target Membership of the same target.

I've tried the usual things like removing the Derived Data folder, but without success. Any ideas what could cause this?

### Edit

The following screenshot shows the error:
[image: Error screenshot]

It's just the following line of code:

```swift
let date = Date().dateByAdding(components: DateComponents(month: -6))
```

Comment: Could you add the code that generates the error?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: It's as simple as `let date = Date().dateByAdding(components: DateComponents(month: -6))`

Comment: Maybe you have another type also named `Date`?

Comment: @Cristik: Not that I'm aware of. ;-) When I Alt-Click on `Date()` Xcode shows the Foundation type help.

Comment: Did you clean the build folder?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: I did many items. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with Xcode 12 beta 2. I opened the project in Xcode 12.5.1 and was able to use the methods in the `Date` Extension without any problem and compile the project.

Now back in Xcode 13 beta 2 the `Date` Extension is found in this class and I can use the methods from it.